# Help with simplifying long expression

Tags: linear-algebra

This is the expression I got after differentiation, can this be simplified?

$10(\ln8x+e^{\cos(x)})^9({1\over x}-e^{\cos(x)}\sin(x))$

Comment: I see factors...

Answer (score 3):

1. No it can't be simplified, really.
2. Derivatives of complicated function compositions tend to be considerably longer than the functions themselves.
3. You think that's a long expression? You ain't seen nothing yet.